# Don't know how to join multipe foreign keys in a single table

Tags: mysql

I created these 4 table:

CITY

| city_id | city |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |
| 4 | DDD |

TRIPS

| trip_id | route_id | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... | ... |

ROUTES

| route_id | city_id(from) | city_id(to) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1(AAA) | 3(CCC) |
| 2 | 1(AAA) | 4(DDD) |

STOPS

| stop_id | route_id | city_on_the_way |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1(AAA->CCC) | 1(AAA) |
| 2 | 1 | 2(BBB) |
| 3 | 1 | 3(CCC) |
| 4 | 2(AAA->DDD) | 1(AAA) |
| 5 | 2 | 2(BBB) |
| 6 | 2 | 3(CCC) |
| 7 | 2 | 4(DDD) |

Im trying to get the trips that pass through city AAA and DDD at the time.
This is what I started with but I just dont know how to join the rest with each other. I tried many things and I keep getting errors. Can someone please explain to me what I need to make this work?

```
SELECT 
 trips.trip_id, 
 city.city AS startpoint, 
 city.city AS endpoint, 
 trips.date, 
 trips.time 
FROM 
 trip
INNER JOIN
 route ON trips.route_id = routes.route_id  
INNER JOIN
 city ON routes.city_id(from) = city.city_id;
```

Comment: That pass through city `AAA` and `DDD`: does it count even if they are starting OR ending points?

Comment: Yes! They can be starting and ending piont aswell

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (updated!):

```
WITH stps AS ( SELECT s.route_id rid, city FROM stops s INNER JOIN cities ON city_id=city_on_the_way )
SELECT  trip_id,  'AAA' city1, 'DDD' city2, dt,  ti 
FROM  trips WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM stps WHERE city='AAA' AND rid=route_id)
              AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM stps WHERE city='DDD' AND rid=route_id)
```

I still believe that the table `ROUTES` is not really helpful in this context. The above code can be seen in action here:
**[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=318f677aa82fd83f9c58b4df4e0c3e52)**.

And I disagree with OP that there must be *two* results: Only trip no. 1 exists in the `trips` table. In my demo I actually added a second record into the `trips` table. Now *both routes* (1 and 2) are linked to trip no. 1, but only route 2 includes both destinations.

Comment: Nope didn't work. I keep getting 1 trip back even though I have two that goes through both AAA and DDD. And I can't specify what stops must a route include example (WHERE city1='AAA' AND city2= 'DDD') :/

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your starting point should be the `stops` table:

```
SELECT
  t.trip_id
FROM stops s
JOIN trips  t ON r.route_id = s.route_id
WHERE s.city_on_the_way IN (
  SELECT CONCAT(city_id, "(", city, ")") as city_on_the_way
  FROM city
  WHERE city IN ("AAA", "DDD")
)
GROUP BY s.route_id, t.trip_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = X 

// Replace X with the number of cities you desire: in this example X = 2  
// So, if you want city AAA, BBB, CCC, X will be 3
```

Comment: This didn't work aswell :/
It gave me back too many errors since we tried selecting the trip_id from stops which didn't have a foreign key for trip_id in it.

Is line 4 correct? Why are we joining trips  t ON r.route_id = r.route_id? xD

Comment: Just a typo. `s` instead of one `r`